# Behaviour of uninitialized C++ structs

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

Say we declare an array of structs in a local scope:

```
    int main()
{
    RandomStruct array [1000];
}
```

Currently the structs in the array are uninitialized. While this means that the struct variables are also uninitialized, does this also mean anything else? Like if I, for example, set all the variables from an unitialized struct to the desired value, and then use functions of this struct, or if I use functions of the struct that don't use uninitialized variables before I set them. Am I correct in thinking that only the variables will be uninitialized and that what the array does is just assign random memory to each of the struct's variables?

Comment: "_Currently the structs in the array are uninitialized._" Default constructor of a struct is invoked. The containing variables (of a struct) are uninitialized, only if default constructor doesn't initialize them.

Comment: Really? Even though the array is local to the main method? @AlgirdasPreidžius

Comment: Why shouldn't the default constructor be invoked, if the array is local?

Comment: "_You are wrong_" Yet, I said "The containing variables (of a struct) are uninitialized, only if default constructor doesn't initialize them.", and default constructor, that is generated by a compiler, doesn't initialize them. Please don't state, that people are wrong, when you didn't read everything they wrote.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Aha, so in the case of structs with local arrays they are constructed by a default constructor generated by a compiler, while, for example in static arrays, they are constructed by the struct's default constructor? Those this also hold for say an array of int? Thank you for this information, I am new to C++.

Comment: @12123232 that doesn't seem like a correct characterization. In both cases, the default ctor is used, and it might be either compiler-generated or user-provided depending on whether you declared one when writing the actual struct definition

Comment: @12123232 "_so in the case of structs with local arrays they are constructed by a default constructor generated by a compiler_" Not necessarily. That's why I wrote my comment. The constructor might be user provided, that can initialize containing variables. Without knowing what `RandomStruct` is, it's impossible to know whether its member values will be initialized or not. If it is, for example `struct RandomStruct {int a; RandomStruct () : a(-1) {}};` - `a` will be initialized to `-1`, every time, regardless of where such construction is being done.

Comment: @nanofarad Oh, I know that a default constructor is generated when there is none defined by the user. Is that what is meant by the default constructor, generated by a compiler? Look at this program: https://pastebin.com/Da6Xc2He, first the struct at ar[3] is what I would say uninitialized and it's variables are uninitialized as can be seen by printing, but if you assign a default constructor to ar[3] then the variables become initialized.

Comment: @12123232 What's meant by "default constructor generated by a compiler" is that, ignoring how you use your struct, if you don't declare/define `RandomStruct::RandomStruct()`, or declare it `RandomStruct() = default`, the compiler generates a default ctor (see "Implicitly-declared default constructor" on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor). You can't "assign a default constructor to `ar[3]`. ... (too long for comment)

Comment: ... What you might mean is that you default-construct a temporary and assign it to `ar[3]` using [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator)

Comment: @nanofarad So basically the default constructor by the compiler doesn't make all the struct members equal to their default values? Is there then any difference between static and local arrays (if we talk about int type for instance, static arrays are initialized with default values while the local have undefined values).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius so if a struct is just struct RandomStruct {int a;}the default constructor doesn't initialize the variable to 0? Even if you write RandomStruct name; and invoke the constructor? Is there any difference at all between static arrays and local arrays (when it comes to the int type the static arrays have default values while local arrays have undefined values).

Comment: @12123232 The implicit default ctor "has the same effect as a user-defined constructor with empty body and empty initializer list" - you might be conflating it with zero initialization which happens for certain storage duration classes; I'm about to run to a meetign but I'll write up a full answer later if applicable

Comment: @12123232 It seems that you are confused about storage durations. This might of, at least, some help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: As an aside, 1000 `RandomStruct`s might be a bit big for automatic variables, depending on how big the struct is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Currently the structs in the array are uninitialized

No, they are [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).

> While this means that the struct variables are also uninitialized

The effect on the members depends on the definition of `RandomStruct`. Depending on that definition, default-initialization of `RandomStruct` *may* have the effect of default-initialization of some or all of the non-static data members of `RandomStruct`. It *may* have the effect eventually of default-initializing a variable of non-class type, as a member of `RandomStruct`, or a member of a member, etc. That variable of non-class type will have an indeterminate value.

> Like if I, for example, set all the variables from an unitialized struct to the desired value, and then use functions of this struct, or if I use functions of the struct that don't use uninitialized variables before I set them

If all members are initialized to determinate values before being used, everything is OK. Member function calls that don't "observe" the indeterminate values are OK.

> Am I correct in thinking that only the variables will be uninitialized and that what the array does is just assign random memory to each of the struct's variables?

That's not quite true. That would imply that observing the indeterminate values is OK but their value is just unknown. It is not. But so long as you don't observe the values, this is a valid intuition.

It is OK to leave them indeterminate so long as they are not observed. But, it is *undefined behavior* to ["observe" the indeterminate value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization#Read_from_an_indeterminate_byte) by producing it in any evaluation, except in very limited, enumerated conditions.

This means that a correct program is not allowed to observe the value, but the compiler is also not required to diagnose it. However, the compiler can assume it is never done (because a correct program cannot do it) and C++ places no requirements on an invalid program.